# how to extract columns from table in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, html-table

My table Structure is

PlayerName|
PlayerNationality|
PlayerPrice|
Checkbox

I am copying the row of the table on check box checked,
using this code

```
$('#one tbody tr td input.checkbox:not(:checked)').on('change',function(e){
    var row=$(this).closest('tr').html();
    $('#two tbody').append('<tr>'+row+'<tr>');
});
```

This code is working fine but I want some clarity:

1. When I am checking the checkbox the whole row gets copied like checkboxes also gets copied what should I do for not copying that checkbox?
2. I want to extract the second table's value, so that I can use them how to do that?
3. Checkboxes are having some values how to get selected checkboxes values too.
4. what to do if I want to delete row on checkbox click?

Like in my second table there will be the same fields, so I should get the player-name of first row or second row and so on for other row as well as other columns.

Comment: Why dont u create JSFiddle And give HTML code ?

Comment: Actually I dont now how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:  http://jsfiddle.net/1u7gz03L/

```
$('#one tbody tr td input.checkbox:not(:checked)').on('change',function(e){

     // question 1
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var tempRow = row.clone();
    $(tempRow ).find('td:last').remove();
    var tds=$(tempRow ).html();

     // question 3 
     var val = $(this).val();
    $('#two tbody').append('<tr>'+tds+'</tr>');
});
```

Comment: Thank s for help but I have tried the first one its not working

Comment: can you please explain me what it actually does?

Comment: Yup its working but small problem is there too.when i check the checkbox from first its not showing the checkbox in second table but it also removing the checkbox from first table.

Comment: Sorry bro I know I will be irritating you but its not working

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli , Hi last line should be `$('#two tbody').append('<tr>'+tds+'<tr>');`

Answer (score 1):

Question 4:

for deleting the row we can use this ..

```
$(document).on("click","#two input[type='checkbox']",function(){      
 $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```